# Polar coordinates integral

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

The exercise is

Evaluate the double integral of the function $f(r, \phi) = r$ in the domain limited by cardioid $r = a(1 + \cos(\phi))$ and the circle $r = a$

If $T$ is the domain, I want

$$\int \int_T r \  dr \ d\phi$$

Now, I know the basic rule about integration; if can change variables and then multiply by the determinant of the resulting jacobian.

My problems are:

1) I don't quite know how to draw the set $T$ on the $xy$ plane.

2) I don't know what change of variables I should be making. I understand that the basic idea is to transform the domain from something "fancy" to a rectangle, but I am having trouble with that

I would like a deep explaination, maybe also on the polar coordinates and how to relate them to the xy plane (apart the obvious $x = r \cos \phi$), how this can be extended to other transformations etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question could be more clear.  First, you write that you want to evaluate the integral

$$\iint\limits_{T} r \, dr \, d\theta.$$

But that is not consistent with the fact that you want to integrate $f(r,\theta)=r$ over the given domain.  Reading that sentence, perhaps you want to evaluate

$$ \iint\limits_{T} r \, dA = \iint\limits_{T} r \, r \, dr \, d\theta.$$

Note that, in polar coordinates, $dA = r\,dr\,d\theta$.

Next, there might be several choices for the domain.

[image]

Assuming the red portion, we get

$$2\int _{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\pi }\int _{a (\cos (\theta)+1)}^ar^2dr\,d\theta =
 \frac{22 a^3}{9}-\frac{\pi  a^3}{2}.$$

Comment: the answer should be $(\frac{22}{9} + \frac{\pi}{2})a^3$.. and anyhow, I'm a little confused: I know I am given the equation in polar coordinates, but the figures I draw are on the xy plane (on the $r \phi$ plane the intersection is just a point!); That should be taken into account, right?

Comment: Could the answer in the book refer to the other part of the domain? So the part in your figure which is white between the cardioid and the circle?

Comment: No, it is written +.. This could also be a print error, I dont know :-) But can you please clarify on how to obtain the result and why it is valid on the xy plane?

Comment: @Ant Done.  I hope that helps.

Comment: okay so if i understand I have to evaluate the integral over the xy plane of the function $f$, so to use polar coordinates (which I already have) I have to multiply for the determinant of the jacobian (r)

Comment: @Ant From my perspective, there's just one plane - polar coordinates and Cartesian coordinates are just two different ways to name points in that one plane. Now, the $dA$ that appears in integration is $dx\,dy$ in Cartesian coordinates but $r\,dr\,d\theta$ in polar coordinates.